# YouTube embedded videos not playing on iOS 9 in Safari

Tags: javascript, youtube, ios9, mobile-safari, embed

I just realized my YouTube embedded videos will not play on iOS devices on my website **unless you click in the top left corner of the video.** Even if I strip out all the extra YouTube parameters (i.e. ?rel=0&showinfo=0 , etc) and go with standard YouTube iFrame embed code, the videos still will not play when I click the center play button.

There have been a few reports of similar issues posted, but these are 4 or 5 years old and they were resolved later by either Apple or YouTube.

**Example Page:** [YouTube video embedded directly in a post](http://protectachild.com/learning/goalkeeper-punts-soccer-ball-into-pool-fence)

We have not made any changes to our website's css or javascript, so I am not sure what caused this or even when it started. I just happened to notice the problem today.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trial and error, I finally figured it out. The problem was caused by the official [MailChimp Wordpress Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp/), which I was not even using anymore. It was still active, so I deactivated it and all YouTube videos began plugin on iOS.

My fault for not starting first with deactivating WP plugin 1 by 1 to test at the beginning. Lesson learned. Hope this helps someone else!